# how can i get the styles of a body tag

Tags: javascript, styles

i have a Body tag. in this tag there are many different css-tags. is there a way to get the styles in a list. e.g. a list of all styles in this tags.

or is there a way to get the defintion of the Body tag?

```
<Body style = "background-Image:url(); background-Color: #ffffff;> .....
```

i tried with:

```
document.body.innerHTML
```

but i get only the Content of this element.

i know the way

```
Body.style.backgroundImage
Body.style.backgroundColor
```

But i have to do this for all styles.

Comment: You can take a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Comment: Thx guy, i don't know why i didn't think about this, i use setAttribute but i forgot getAttribute. Thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

`document.body.style;`

Just get the style from the body object.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try with this:

```
$(document.body).attr('style');
```

Comment: This uses [JQuery](https://jquery.com/), which doesn't need to be included to accomplish finding the style of the body element.  So it is unnecessary overhead.